# How to Enable Keep alive in Play Framework in java

Tags: playframework

I m trying to set keep alive for my application. using the below property for netty server and running application in prod mode.

But not able to set keep alive for Connection in response. Can anyone please help.

```
 play.server {

    provider = "play.core.server.NettyServerProvider"
    netty {
        eventLoopThreads = 0
        maxInitialLineLength = 4096
        maxChunkSize = 8192
        log.wire = false
        transport = "jdk"
    option {
       SO_BACKLOG = 100
      child {
          SO_KEEPALIVE = true
            TCP_NODELAY = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SO_KEEPALIVE is a TCP option, and is a connection keepalive on the TCP layer. 
HTTP keepalive is re-using an existing connection to the same host instead of closing and reopening. Play by default does HTTP keepalive. If you want control, I suggest to put nginx in front it, which allows more control over the behaviour.